# Can I label GCP API keys to aggregate metrics and billing data?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

For services like translation API and maps API I generate api keys for services to use by going to "APIs & Services" and generating a key.

Can I apply labels to these keys? I can't see where to do that.

I want to aggregate metrics and billing data by API key labels so I can see what keys are running up the most cost and usage. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add labels to those API keys.

What you can do is create a different project (and therefore use a different API key) for each application. Then, when you view billing reports grouped by project, you'll be able to break down usage/cost by project.

Here are some relevant documentations:

- [Billing reports](https://developers.google.com/maps/reporting-and-monitoring/reporting#billing-rpt)
- [Group by](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports#group-by)